# Not able to enumerate all properties of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbee with javascript and have the following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <object classid="clsid:f6D90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00C04f990bb4" id="abc">
    </object>
    <script>
    var b=document.getElementById("abc");
    for (a in b){
        document.write(a+"<br>");
    }
    alert(b.object);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, my question is why doesnt this code enumerates all the properties for the object b.
And to be more specific, this code does not enumerates the "object" property. But the code alert(b.object) tells me that this is an object.

Am I doing everything right? can someone clarify my doubts.

Thanks

Comment: Not all properties are enumerable, but in this case, `b.object` does not exist: http://jsfiddle.net/BrkyZ/, so I wonder what `alert(b.object)` actually gave you. If you could create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that shows the behaviour you saw, that would be great.

Comment: Well, what are you expecting?  What is that `<object>` you've got in there?  What is it supposed to do?  Where is `a` being defined?

Comment: @tkone: It belongs to MSXML 3.0 core services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). U can try running it on ur own system as well.

Comment: @FelixKling: which properties are not enumerable? and is there any way to enumerate those?

Comment: @FelixKling : I am running that code on IE, so I doubt a web site like jsfiddle will be able to do that. U can see the behavior I saw using IE to run this code and I saw [object] being alerted.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear from your comment, but you should rather add this information to your question as well. I'm on a Mac, so no IE ;)

Comment: @user1466594 no i can't.  i'm on a mac!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enumerate all properties (both own or inherited, both enumerable or non-enumerable) of an object, do this:

```
do {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj ).forEach(function ( prop ) {
        // process prop       
    });
} while ( obj = Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ) );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/L899Z/3/

Comment: Vidas: I see that this works on jsfiddle, but its not working on IE, how can I make it run on IE?

Comment: By the way I have never used jsfiddle

Comment: @user1466594 Uh, I forgot to close the `<object>` element. I've updated my demo. It works in IE9, now. Btw, it is not possible to make this work in IE8 and before, since those browsers don't provide a method to retrieve non-enumerable property names, or to retrieve the implicit prototype link.

Comment: Can you give me the complete code with all the content..Sorry for being such a newb.. :(

Comment: @user1466594 Go here - http://jsfiddle.net/L899Z/3/show/light/ - and view the source code of that page. That's the source code of the demo.

Comment: Thanks :D can I do this recursively and mark every thing accordingly, like mark object as object, attribute as attribute and method as method..?

Comment: @user1466594 In my code above, at `// process prop`, you can put your code. For instance, you can analyze the type of the value of the property. (The property value is accessible via `obj[prop]`.)

Comment: just did the exact thing and got the type for most properties with exception to some..now there was a certain method I was looking for which could have been accessed via obj.object.definition()..how would I be able to reach to this..  I did change var obj = document.getElementById( 'abc' ); to var obj = document.getElementById( 'abc' ).object; to try and get the definition method, but couldnt get it, any ideas?

Comment: So how many properties does your new `obj` object have? Is it an object at all? (you can test via `obj instanceof Object`)

Comment: hey tested it via alert(obj.object) and the alert box says object.. thats about it..am i doing it right?

Comment: alert(obj.object) and alert(typeof obj.object) give the same result i.e. [object]..so how I will enumerate its properties and methods?

Comment: @user1466594 So when you define obj as `var obj = document.getElementById( 'abc' ).object;`, and then execute the code from my answer, how many properties do you get? (Replace `// process prop`, with `alert(prop)` or `console.log(prop)` to test...)

Comment: none..and did u get a chance to test it on IE your own system?

Comment: @user1466594 I tested in IE9. It is an object that has no own properties, and that doesn't inherit from any other object (its [[Prototype]] link is `null`). That `definition` method you mentioned above, is probably added subsequently by some script (or it is added once you initialize the OBJECT element).

Comment: so is there any way using which I can get all the methods once I initialize elements like these? If you want to see what the complete code that performs the definition method is, plz let me know..

Comment: and any references that are short yet excellent for javascript that would be really helpful in getting these things in my head?

Comment: @user1466594 I've found it - it's listed in the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It appears to be an IE-specific thing, since it's *not* listed in the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLObjectElement). Anyways, the MSDN page states that this property "retrieves the contained object", which is the object that is loaded into the `<object>` element. So, the `definition()` method is defined on that object, and has nothing to do with the `<object>` element itself.

Comment: So, first you have to initialize the `<object>` element, by loading your object into it, and *then* you can retrieve the `<object>.object` object, and enumerate its properties (using the code from my answer).